# Focusing on inputs in divs, using arrow keys (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html

I have three div elements, with text inputs inside. I need to make it possible to be able to navigate between parent divs to focus on child inputs, while using arrow keys (to go back and forth from one input to another). How to achieve this without using jQuery, just vanilla Js?

I tried using loops, by selecting siblings with class to move between elements, but for some reason it's not working.

```html
<div>
  <input class="move" type="text">
</div>
<div>
  <input class="move" type="text">
</div>
<div>
  <input class="move" type="text">
</div>
```

```js
const myInput = document.querySelectorAll(".move");

myInput.forEach((el) => {
    el.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 37) {
            if (this.previousElementSibling) {
                this.previousElementSibling.focus();
            }
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
            if (this.nextElementSibling) {
                this.nextElementSibling.focus();
            }
        }
    }, false)
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/annoh/znq52bda/

I'm currently learning Js, so I might've done something wrong, but I don't get any syntax errors within the code. Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `this.parentElement.previousELementSibling` and `this.parentElement.nextELementSibling` to check for previous/next parent element exists or not and then go into the sibling parent element's child to focus on the previous input. Js code is as follows-

```
const myInput = document.querySelectorAll(".move");

myInput.forEach((el) => {
    el.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 37) {
        console.log(event.keyCode);
            if (this.parentElement.previousElementSibling != undefined) {
                this.parentElement.previousElementSibling.getElementsByClassName("move")[0].focus();
            }
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
            if (this.parentElement.nextElementSibling != undefined) {
                 this.parentElement.nextElementSibling.getElementsByClassName("move")[0].focus();
            }
        }
    }, false)
})
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ashhaq12345/mw7L43ct/